# On the definition of clone of relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

I am reading [A short introduction to clones](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S1571066114000322/1-s2.0-S1571066114000322-main.pdf?_tid=24b58926-bb48-11e4-86ed-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1424688105_29f68790a0b8f9ceba0f16f7391c2f33/) and I am stuck at this definition ($A$ is a set and $R_A$ the set of finitary relations on $A$)

**Definition** A subset $R\subseteq R_A$ is called a clone of relations on $A$ if:

(i) $\varnothing\in R$

(ii) $R$ is closed under general superposition, that is, the following holds: for an arbitrary index set $I$, let $\sigma_i\in R^{(k_i)}$ ($i\in I$) and let $\phi:k\longmapsto\alpha$ and $\phi_i:k_i\longmapsto\alpha$ be mappings where $\alpha$ is some cardinal number. Then the relation defined by
$${\displaystyle\bigwedge}^{\phi}_{(\phi_i)_{i\in I}} (\sigma_i)_{i\in I}:=\{r\circ \phi| \forall i\in I: r\circ \phi_i\in \sigma_i,r\in A^{\alpha}\}$$
belongs to $R$.

Here are some questions:

1) What is $k$?

2) What does it mean that $\phi_i$ is a map? What is a map from a number to a number?

3) I know what the composition of two or many relations is, but what is meant here by $r\circ \phi_i$?

Answer (score 2):

**Here are some questions:**

**1) What is $k$?**

$k$ is the natural number that is the arity of the relation mentioned in part (ii) of the definition.

**2) What does it mean that $\phi_i$ is a map? What is a map from a number to a number?**

map=function.

**3) I know what the composition of two or many relations is, but what is meant here by $r\circ \phi_i$?**

$r\circ  \phi_i$ is the composition of the function $r\colon \alpha\to A$ with the function $\phi_i\colon k_i\to \alpha$. It is therefore a function $k_i\to A$, hence is a potential element of $\sigma_i$, since $\sigma_i\subseteq A^{k_i}$.